# Why is FormDeactivate called before the form is closed?

Tags: c#, winforms, excel-interop, winforms-interop

I have a Winforms app that generates an Excel spreadsheet using Excel Interop.

When I tried to save the sheet this way:

```
_xlBook.SaveAs(filename, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

...it would fail, telling me, "*System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233049 
  Message=COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.*"

This didn't make much sense, though - I wasn't doing anything fancy with threads or such; this is a pretty plain vanilla utility. The only other places _xlBook is referenced in the code are:

1)

```
private Excel.Workbook _xlBook;
```

2)

```
_xlBook = _xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
```

3)

```
_xlSheets = _xlBook.Worksheets;
_xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[1];
```

4)

```
_xlBook.Close(false);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlBook);
```

That last part, where _xlBook is disposed of, was called from the form's Deactivate event, which was:

```
private void FormMain_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DeinitializeExcelObjects();
}
```

The problem was (which I discovered after putting breakpoints in all the places where _xlBook is referenced) that FormMain_Deactivate() was being called *prior to* _xlBook.SaveAs() being called, which is called when a "Run" button is clicked.

Once I commented out the call to DeinitializeExcelObjects() in FormMain_Deactivate(), and called it instead right after the call to _xlBook.SaveAs(), it works fine - the file is created and saved without any err msg.

So why is FormDeactivate called before the form is closed? If this is somehow "as designed," the event is terribly misnamed.

Comment: Well `Deactivate` is called any time the `Form` looses focus so it stands to reason that its called when closing. And it *is* consistent with the method `Form.Activate()`.

Comment: Right, but it shouldn't be closing at that time.

Comment: What makes you think it is closing? Does the "Run" button do more than just call `SaveAs`? I can imagine a form deactivates when for instance you're asking the user for a destination file name?

Comment: [Order of Events in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx): When an application closes, the shutdown events of the main form are raised in the following order:
`Form.Closing`, 
`Form.FormClosing`, 
`Form.Closed`, 
`Form.FormClosed`, 
`Form.Deactivate`. 
The `ApplicationExit` event of the `Application` class is raised after the shutdown events of the main form.  [Form.Deactivate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate(v=vs.110).aspx) Occurs when the form loses focus and is no longer the active form.

Comment: It doesn't need to close. Just loosing focus will make your event handler release the RCW.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: That's my point; Deactivate should be the very last thing; I haven't closed the form when the Deactivate event was getting called. It was being called in the middle of code within a button event handler.

Comment: @InBetween: If that's true (losing focus calls Deactivate), I think it's a bad design, or at least a bad name for the event.

Comment: If you are debugging then the form will lose focus anytime you activate the debugging window and hence the RCW will be released prematurely.

Comment: @InBetween: That must be the answer (debugging); BTW, the word is "lose" not "loose" (and "losing" not "loosing")

Comment: Well thats a matter of taste. Like I said, setting focus on a form is called `Activate()`. Don't assume what something means simply looking at its name, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: You've put your code in the wrong place. Seems you've misunderstood what Activate and Deactivate mean (at least as far as Windows is concerned). OnDeactivate is called whenever a different window is activated, and clearly when your form is being destroyed another window will have to become activated (even if that window is the desktop). It can also be called multiple times (such as when focus changes to a different application and back, or even a different form in your own app). If you want the code to run when the form is closed, put the code in the Close event handler instead.

Comment: @KenWhite: Make that an answer and I'll knight it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've put your code in the wrong place. :-) It seems you've misunderstood what activation and deactivation mean (at least as far as Windows is concerned).

Deactivation happens whenever a different window is activated, and clearly when your form is being destroyed a different window has to become active, even if that window is the Windows desktop. *FormDeactivate* can be called multiple times (such as when the user switches to a different app, or even a different window within your own app). It's important to note that this also applies to *activation*; *FormActivate* can fire multiple times as well.

If you want code to run when your form is being closed, put it in the *FormClose* event handler instead.